# How can we get code coverage for multiple applications in a single Visual Studio solution using dotCover? (command-line)

Tags: resharper, dotcover

Here are JetBrains' instructions for a *single* application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
  <TargetExecutable>D:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6\bin\nunit-console.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>AppTests.dll AppTests2.dll AppTests3.dll</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>D:\Projects\TheApplication\bin\Debug</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>AppCoverageReport.html</Output>
  <ReportType>html</ReportType>
</AnalyseParams>
```

source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html

Our Visual Studio solution has multiple applications (in a single Visual Studio solution) that we want to get code coverage for in our Jenkins build.  We are looking to integrate this into our CI/CD pipeline (so seeking a command-line solution).  This is analogous to running cover on the entire solution inside Visual Studio IDE.

(The applications obviously share common library projects, but we want all C# projects to be reported once each.  We prefer to avoid manually maintaining multiple XML configuration files and merging the results, i.e., one XML per C# project, as we have 50+ projects.)

Comment: From your question, it's not quite clear what you're going to analyze. If you analyze tests coverage, then the example from the docs is OK: 'AppTests.dll AppTests2.dll AppTests3.dll' represent different test projects within a solution. Or you want to analyze application coverage and your app consists of multiple exe files? In this case, you can create a .bat file that runs them all and specify this .bat file as a TargetExecutable.

Comment: @darthWeirdo wouldn't that be a maintenance headache? Everytime someone adds a new test project, they would have to remember to update that batch script. I was hoping for a mode automated way to detect and execute all the tests by wild cards. Example: Cover all test projects with pattern "*.Unit.Tests"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing. The only thing that comes to my mind right now is this: Write a powershell script that detects and copies all the dlls that you want into a directory. We use this as a target directory and setup a space delimited list of dlls.

Comment: @VinShahrdar No, we have not found a solution.  We are still generating individual XML files and merging them into a final report.  In the last few weeks, there were some updates on the JetBrains thread https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-9681, but our DevOps crew is still trying to evaluate if those comments are relevant (it isn't clear to me if it solves our issue, so we need to take a stab at implementing to assess).